# Whitespace lost with fixme PDF margin notes (pdfcmargin)

Tags: pdftex, white-space, fixme

When using the fixme package with pdfmargin layout a whitespace is lost.

This minimal example

```
\pdfoutput=1
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixme}
\fxsetup{draft,layout=pdfmargin}
\begin{document}
Hello \fxnote*{capitalize?}{world}!
\end{document}
```

produces the following output – note the missing space between the two words:
[image: pdflatex output]

This seems to be related to the margin placement of the PDF note as replacing the layout with `layout=pdfnote` (or other layouts) does not exhibit the problem.

How can this be fixed?

NB: As a workaround, I can use `Hello ~\fxnote*{capitalize?}{world}!` but obviously this is not fully satisfactorily;-)

This is for fixme version 2019/01/03 v4.5.